# Complex circles with images inside

Tags: html, css, image, frontend

Im trying to create a circle with a image inside and a rectangle in the footer of this circle..

it's more easy show that explain: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ao6W.png

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/77b34nh0/

I'm a little lost, how can i do the info box that is on the footer of the circle?

Thanks.

Code:

HTML:

```
<img class="wow rotateIn" src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/">
```

CSS:

```
img {
    margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
    width: 254px;
    height: 254px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #f98835; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

1. Wrap the image in a container
2. Make the container `position:relative` - this allows you to position your `.caption` div relative to this parent div
3. Absolutely position the rectangle relative to the bottom of the container div

HTML

```
<div class="circle_image_box_with_caption">
    <img class="wow rotateIn" src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/">
    <div class="caption">
        This is my caption text
    </div>
</div>
```

or with HTML5

```
<figure class="circle_image_box_with_caption">
    <img class="wow rotateIn" src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/">
    <figcaption class="caption"> <!-- don't need the class really since it's already a semantic element and can be targeted in css with .circle_image_box_with_caption figcaption -->
        This is my caption text
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

CSS

```
.circle_image_box_with_caption {
    position:relative;
    width: 254px;
    height: 254px;

}
.circle_image_box_with_caption img {
    margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #f98835; 
}
.circle_image_box_with_caption .caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/77b34nh0/2/

Comment: Keep in mind above method does not work with images that aren't square without messing up the image proportion.

Comment: Bonus points if you use a `<figure>` with `<figcaption>` element for semantics.

Comment: Thanks very much jona, sea and barry!